# Data Validation List in excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, list

I am trying to add values to the cell in a list format if certain criteria is met. I initially was unable to assign the values directly so i created an Array to old the values that meet the criteria. however now when i try to assign the values of the array to a cell in a list format with the below code i get a

> type mismatch error

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan").Cells(i, 5).Validation.Add _
      Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Formula1:=Join(St, ",")
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this or if there is a way to assign the values directly without holding them in an array. remember the list is not continuous an it only needs to select the values that meet my condition.

```
Sub try() 
Dim j,k As Long 
Dim c As Range 
Dim st As Object 
Set st=CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 
For j=5 To 150 
If(Workbook.Sheets("Plan").Cells(i,1)= Workbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(j,1))Then 
    For k= 6 To 150 
        If(Workbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(j,k)<>"") Then
            For Each c In Workbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(1,k)
                Select Case c.Value 
                    Case"Starch" st.Add Workbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(3,k)
                EndSelect 
            Nextc 
        EndIf 
    Next k 
EndIf 
Next j 

Workbook.Sheets("Plan").Cells(i,5).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
              AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(st,",") 

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show how you get `St`

Comment: Hi Tim, Find my complete code below:

Comment: You can edit your question to add your code - it's difficult to read in a comment

Comment: Maybe try `Join(st.ToArray,",")`  You need to get your ArrayList into e "regular" array before you can pass it to `Join`

Comment: Hi Tim, i tried Join(st.ToArray,",") however i get a application defined or object defined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your ArrayList into a regular array before you can pass it to `Join`.

Eg:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim st As Object

    Set st = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    st.Add "A"
    st.Add "B"
    st.Add "C"

    'Debug.Print Join(st, ",")         'fails with "Type Mismatch"
    Debug.Print Join(st.toarray, ",") 'Works >> A,B,C

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
        AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(st.toarray, ",")

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim i had another query related to this. once i have all my drop downs generated. now if i select a value in one drop down i need to also make sure the same value is not selected in any other drop down through my sheet. is that possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible - you can look at using Conditional formatting for example.

Comment: i have checked conditional formatting however there is an option for highlighting duplicates. Is there any other way apart from that one?

Comment: it would be best to post a new question for this, and explain exactly what the behaviour should be.  You want to *prevent* chosing the same value, just warn the user, or ?  How many cells need to be monitored?  Etc.

Comment: hi tim i have posted a new question for this however i havent got a useful answer yet and seeing that you helped on the previous query i was hoping you could on this one as well.